# Meaning of an And Phrase followed by an Or Phrase

Tags: conjunctions, legalese

A sentence begins like "If A and B or C then ..." does that mean that A must always be true and one of B or C must be true for the following to happen?    Or can just C be true?   In programming or math you could put parenthesis around the phrases to clarify your meaning.  You could write "If A and (B or C), then...".   The reason I ask, is the 25th Amendment of the US Constitution reads:

> Whenever the Vice President and a majority of either the principal officers of the executive departments or of such other body as Congress may by law provide,

Comment: This is not 'A and B or C'. It's 'A and a majority of either B or C'. The first type of sentence is inherently ambiguous, as has been discussed here before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your structure states is that the possible combinations are only two:

either

> ***A and a majority of B***

or

> ***A and a majority of C***

(***A and B and C*** can never happen)